# Difference between document.referrer and window.parent.location.href

Tags: javascript, iframe

Here's the situation: there is a site, and it belongs to the client, so it's not on my domain, lets say `client.com`.

On this site there is an `iframe`, the source of this `iframe` is a simple js code, which loads another js (`client.js`) - this code is on my domain.

What I need to do is to get the exact url of the page where the iframe is. So now I'm trying to fugure out the difference between `document.referrer` and `window.parent.location.href` with no luck.

Both give me exactly what I need, but I can't realize what is more reliable? Is there a situation, where one will work and another won't?

Comment: `referrer` = from which site did you come
`location.href` = the actual URI

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`document.referrer` gives you the URI of the page that linked to the current page. This is a value that's available for all pages, not just frames.

`window.parent` gives you the parent *frame*, and its `location` is its URI.

If you want to find the URI of the parent frame, then use `window.parent.location`.

Comment: May `window.parent.location` work incorrectly somehow? And can different domains be a problem?

Comment: Not sure I can give an authoritative answer, but if there is no parent frame or your script does not have the correct cross-site permissions to access it it will fail. There's probably a way better solution than sniffing parent frame URIs for all this though, but it's impossible to say without more details.

Comment: What details do you need? :) I never experienced any error in this approach, but I want to be sure about it...

Comment: Neither `document.referrer` nor `window.parent.location` will work on cross-origin requests.

Comment: document. referer is not working in internet explorer...how to solve this

Answer (score 13):

The main difference is that the `document.referrer` will point to the page which linked to the current page inside the iframe. If your iframe content contain links, which allows to navigate through a few pages, then only the first page loaded inside the iframe will have parent frame URI as `document.referrer`.
Each page loaded by clicking link inside the iframe will have the uri of the page containing link in the `document.referrer`.

At the same time `window.parent.location` will always contain the URI of the page in parent window, but it will be accessible only if the site origin is the same. 
Read about [relaxing site origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Relaxing_the_same-origin_policy) to see what should be done on both your and your client sites, so you can access the data.

That being said, I would rather give your client something like a service key or token, which will authorize his site to use your iframed app, and which will authenticate the caller as your client, so you can know that the call is from his site.

Comment: Iframe has no content - it's used just to call code loader. Ordinary our clients use this loader directly (just insert `<script>...</script>` in the page) but sometimes iframe is the only way

Comment: I see. I have assumed that this is some sort of app that one can embed on his page.

Comment: @SWilk: I have links navigation inside my iframe and I am getting URI of  iframe application instead of application which contain Iframe, can you please advise how can I get URI of iframe hosted application inside the pages where I am navigating inside the Iframe.

Comment: @ChupChapCharli: I do not fully understand your problem from this description.
Consider posting a question with code examples. Maybe then someone will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

"document.location.ancestorOrigins" is more feasible option.