# get url of window.history.go(-2)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I used `window.history.go(-2)` it redirects but I don't want to redirect I want to print the URL (to know the referrer), Example: I'm navigate  `file1->file2->file3`, I wrote the script `window.history.go(-2)` in `file3`, and I want the alert as `'file1'`. Can anybody help me please?

If not possible is there a way to get the referrer URL, and I'm in a iframe, from the frame I want the sites referral URL.

Comment: For safety/security/privacy reasons, this is not possible.

Comment: Keep it in the session may be?

Comment: then how can i get the referrer url of site being in iframe  using php or javascript

Comment: You would need to track the user's navigation separately via some persistent variable, like LocalStorage

Answer (score 0):

It is a violation of privacy and it is not possible easily.
You can read [this](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070228/steal-browser-history-without-javascript/) to check the history of similar attempts. Nowadays it is way harder.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to go back the browser history via history.go, but not to get the url locations from it. However, if you click some link and entered the page, you can use the `document.referrer` property to get the referrer url. Refer this link for more info.

[Difference between document.referrer and window.parent.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413903/difference-between-document-referrer-and-window-parent-location-href)